# How to format tick mark number style?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How do I use a number format, for instance x0.00%, for a numerical value label on a Matplotlib x- or y-axis tick label? For example, I'd like the number 0.00125 to show as the label 0.125%. I'm plotting histograms with 1, 2, and 3 sigma of daily stock returns. Usually the values are in the less than 1.00% range, but occasionally can be >10.0000% for +/- 3 sigma. So I'll have labels that are as small as 0.0010% to as large as 10.0000%. Yes, the tails are fat; the stocks are thinly traded; or there is a flash crash/recovery. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try using a [`PercentFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter)? It wasn't written with fat tails or flash crashes in mind, but might do the trick nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `matplotlib.ticker` which helps you format each tick.
In this example code I've rounded each value to three decimal places, and replaced the minus sign with one I wanted.

You could add conditional statements for different values of x or y, and specify what kind of ticker you want!

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_formatter(y, pos):
    label = "-" + str(-round(y, 3)) if y < 0 else str(round(y, 3))
    return label

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_formatter(x, pos):
    label = "-" + str(-round(x, 3)) if x < 0 else str(round(x, 3))
    return label

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)
```